# Failed to use jenkins to deploy a WAR to remote server

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

This is my configuration:
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F3z7.jpg)

And there is console output:

> war:
>         [war] Building war: /home/zhaowz/.jenkins/jobs/huamei-farm-web/workspace/build/huamei.war
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 7 seconds ERROR: Step ‘Deploy war/ear to
>   a container’ aborted due to exception:  java.io.IOException: Expecting
>   Ant GLOB pattern, but saw
>   '/home/zhaowz/.jenkins/jobs/huamei-farm-web/workspace/build/huamei.war'.
>   See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax    at
>   hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1738)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.access$1700(FilePath.java:190)    at
>   hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1719)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1716)     at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1716)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1701)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1687)  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:59)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410) Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a relative path in WAR/EAR files:

```
**/*.war
```

Comment: Ok,I looks like I can transport the war file to the remote container now,but there is still an error

Comment: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/home/zhaowz/.jenkins/jobs/huamei-farm-web/workspace/build/huamei.war]
 at

Comment: Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /huamei

Comment: Is everything ok in your config (check the root context)? Is there another instance of Tomcat running on the same port?

Comment: Thank you,I found I have filled the wrong password in the jenkins config.

Comment: Why no one mentions this anywhere. Thanks.